# Node.js , on server Side get value for cookie connect.sid key

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am new to node.Js. I am creating a session for a chat app and using socket.io to get connect.sid cookie value, which I want for finding logged in client. How to get the value of connect.sid key in Express?

Thank you!